# Cordova and Ionic: plugin not updating

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

I have a question concerning plugins. I am using the ionic framework (http://ionicframework.com/) and Cordova for my hybrid app. I am using 
a toast (text popup) plugin to provide some feedback. Everything works but
I decided that I needed some customization so I edited some of the .java files.
It seems that my edit has no impact, it's really strange, the plugin also seems to keep
working even when I comment out the execute function.

I am using the following ionic command to test the app on my smartphone: "ionic run android"

Any idea why the plugin is not updating? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you change plugin code? in your project or in location from where you did install the plugin?

Comment: I installed the plugin using this command: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git. And than I edited its .java files

Comment: I didn't use `ionic run android` command but run from Eclipse. I'm not sure that this command compiles your project. It only takes project apk and runs on connected device. Compile project first.

Comment: I am using webstorm for my whole project, any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Can you see the plugin changes under these folder `platforms/android/src/<package name or directory>/<filename.java>`?

Answer (score 3):

I had issues with plugins as well and decided to remove/add them back in, then update platform and it worked.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.<plugin>
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.<plugin>
cordova platform update <platform>
```

Comment: but this will just download the plugin from the internet repository it doesn't updates the plugin

Answer (score 2):

When I remove my android platform and install it back it works (it seems the only place where it installs plugins)